# Convert to MM/YYYY format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date, datetime

I have some bad data in the database for a varchar field.
Data includes:

```
10/2012
May, 2010
August., 2010
05/10/2009
```

But now I need to clean up these data & update the column with MM/YYYY format. Anyone has any suggestions for doing this easier?

Comment: Why not use a `DATETIME` column instead of keeping a `VARCHAR` where this can happen again?

Comment: I agree. But this has been designed to store string values as well. So now UI will not send the bad format to MM/YYYY. Even if I'm to use DATETIME, I have to process this bad data and convert to MM/YYYY

Comment: Not contesting that, just saying that using `VARCHAR` caused the problem in the first place, so you should cleanup and migrate to a `DATETIME` instead (and change the client to pass in a proper `DateTime` too).

Comment: @Oded: Isn't the OP asking how to cleanup?

Comment: @Gabe - I took `update the column with MM/YYYY format` to mean that the migration would be back to the same `VARCHAR` column...

Comment: @Oded: It's very awkward to use a `datetime` column to hold a month and year without a day. I would likely not recommend it.

Comment: @Gabe - Possibly, though `VARCHAR` is still not right. You could use `DATETIME` and always use `1` for the day. There are other alternatives to `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a months/year conversion table using spt_values to create the combinations of months and years you're looking for.

Then join it by formatting the month/year values to conform to the different versions. Note you only have to do this for where ISDATE(field) <> 1

```
;With ConversionTable as (
SELECT 
    months.number month, 
    years.number year,
    right('00' + cast( months.number as varchar(2)), 2) 
    + '/' + cast(years.number as char(4)) Final
FROM  
     master..spt_values months
    CROSS JOIN master..spt_values years 
WHERE 
     months.NUMBER  between 1 and 12
     and months.type = 'P'
     AND years.NUMBER  between 2000 and 2012
     and years.type = 'P')


SELECT t.baddate , ct.final
FROM 
    TEST t
    INNER JOIN 
    ConversionTable  ct 
    ON t.BadDate = 
         DateName( month , DateAdd( month , ct.month , 0 ) - 1 ) 
         + ', '
         + cast(ct.year as char(4)) 
    OR
      t.BadDate = 
         DateName( month , DateAdd( month , ct.month , 0 ) - 1 ) 
         + '., '
         + cast(ct.year as char(4)) 
    OR 
         t.BadDate = ct.Final

   --- Add more OR statements for your different varieties 
WHERE
     ISDATE(t.badDate) <> 1
UNION
SELECT 
     t.BadDate ,  
        right('00'  + cast(MONTH(Cast(t.BadDate as datetime)) as varchar(2)),2) + '/'
       + cast(year(Cast(t.BadDate as datetime)) as varchar(4))
FROM
     test t
WHERE
     ISDATE(t.badDate) = 1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ccf6/33)

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

```
SELECT badDate,
right(convert(varchar(10),cast(replace(CASE len(badDate) - len(replace(badDate, '/', '')) WHEN 1 THEN substring(badDate,1,2)+'/01/'+right(badDate,4) ELSE badDate END,'.', '') AS datetime),103),7)
FROM test
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e0ca/8/0)

Comment: Nice. Here's the [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e0ca/6) if you want to include it your answer. As a side note you might want to consider adding some text to describe your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this in code (not sure what languages are available). Most languages will have much richer support for date time handling and exception handling compared to plain sql.

This is especially true if you have to support SQL Server 2000 and 2005 as well as 2008.